# Closing a form and doing something on return to another form

Tags: c#

I have a mainForm and a saveForm.
I never close the mainForm, just let the saveForm appear over the top.

When i close the saveForm, I want a piece of code to run on returning to mainForm.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @benPearce's answer, if you are content to have saveForm appear modally, then you can just call:

So in the `mainForm`, I am assuming you have a Save button (let's call it `btnSave`) of some kind that brings up `saveForm`, right?  Right.  So double click on that Save button and Visual Studio will create an event handler for you.  Type in the code below.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    saveForm sf = new SaveForm();
    if (sf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // do your thing
    }
}
```

Of course, you have to make sure that the saveForm is setting the DialogResult.  For instance, assuming you have an OK button in the `saveForm` that is supposed to close the `saveForm`...  In the Click event for the OK button you would do this:

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: @Luke.  You would do this in the mainForm.

Comment: Inside a method? Which one? Just a bit confused about how this works?

Comment: Thats really helpful, but I dont want it to do the code when I click the save button as you call it.
After closing the saveForm, I want it to do something. 
Is the code you have provided doing this?

Comment: @Luke.  Yes the code does exactly what you want, but only if you want your saveForm to be modal.  If not, then you should go with @benPearce approach.  


Also, when you say that you do not want a save button...how exactly are kicking off the saveForm then?

Comment: At the moment, I have it loaded from mainForm_load but I'm not happy with that and won't be reloading the form. I do open the saveForm with a button. My idea is that the code will happen on initial launch, and then when I close the saveForm, but without using formload. I will try what you said.

Answer (score 2):

In mainForm, subscribe to the FormClosed event on the saveForm, put your code in the event handler for this event

```
void saveForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    /// code here
}
```