# C# Calling a method from another Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, oop, forms

Hi
I have 2 Form Form1 and Form2

Form1 have a table and there is my records and there is a Void for refresh the table in the Form1.

Form2 is my insert form I am insertig data to sqlserver.I wantto that When after i save the record in Form2 to run Form1 Refresh void.(when Form1,Form2 opened)

thanks.

Comment: Does Form1 open Form2 directly?

Comment: Sory my english not good

Comment: So call the `Refresh` method immediately after the `Form2.ShowDialog()` call returns. Simple as that.

Comment: When Form2 closes, you could refresh Form1? Or set the Owner of Form2 to be Form1 and call the Refresh method that way.

Comment: I am making like it but how can i call a method from another class

Comment: You don't have to call the method from another class. `Refresh` is defined in the `Form1` class, and you're calling it from code in `Form1`. Calling a method from one class in another class is almost always a bad idea; it indicates that you have a poorly-designed application. I highly recommend that you get a book on object-oriented programming in .NET and make sure that you understand what this means.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closing a form and doing something on return to another form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671000/closing-a-form-and-doing-something-on-return-to-another-form)

Answer (score 5):

Form2 will have to have a reference to the instance of Form1. You can pass this reference to Form2 when the insert button is clicked:

```
Form2 insertForm = new Form2();
//Form2.ShowDialog(Me); - Correction - 'Me' is for VB. in C# it's:
Form2.ShowDialog(this);
```

Next on Form2 you can access Form1 like this:

```
(Form1)this.Parent.RefreshTable();
```

Answer (score 2):

try this to call method from another form :

```
if (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["ParentFormName"] != null)
    {
        (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["ParentFormName"] as   ParentFormName).MethodName(args);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Form1, when you open Form2, attach to Form2 `OnClose/Closed` event, or a custom `Save` event, which when raised, refreshes the table in form 1.

Comment: See my comment to Akram's answer. This is an easy way to create a memory leak, not really a good idea for a beginning .NET programmer. You have to make sure that you explicitly *remove* the event handler, and ensure the child form gets disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the construct for Form2 so it takes an extra parameter, like this:

```
...
private Form1 mainWindow;
public Form2(Form1 mainWindow)
{
   this.mainWindow = mainWindow;
}
...
public void HaveSavedSql()
{
   this.mainWindow.RefreshAll();
}
```

You should consider however looking up on [Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) so you can seperate concerns. Interfaces are useful for many things!