# C# form needs to call method defined in parent form

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a form (`EmployeeForm`) that inherits from a partial class form (`MainForm`).  Inside `MainForm` I have a method (`SaveSomething`) that I want to call.

How do I do this?

```
using SomeLib;

namespace FooEmployee
{
    public partial class EmployeeForm: MainForm
    {
        private void dgv_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             SaveSomething();
        }
    }    
}

namespace SomeLib
{
    public partial class MainForm: Form
    {
        private bool SaveSomething()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743611/c-sharp-calling-a-method-from-another-form

Comment: @AwesomeProgrammer: While I'd be willing bet there is a duplicate around it doesn't look like that question qualifies since there is no mention of one form inheriting from another. That question is also of poor quality in my opinion anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Use `protected` as the access modifier on your method as opposed to `private`.

`private` means only for the class that the method is contained within. `protected`, on the other hand, means the current class and all that inherit from it.

Your code will look like this:

```
public partial class MainForm: Form
{
    protected bool SaveSomething()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This is called an [Access Modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173121.aspx), the link is to an MSDN article on all of the available access modifiers in C# ([`public`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/yzh058ae.aspx), [`private`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/st6sy9xe.aspx), [`protected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bcd5672a.aspx), [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/7c5ka91b.aspx), and `protected internal`).

Comment: Rudi, I understand the protected access modifier and I have implemented this, but I'm getting an error when referencing the "SaveSomething()" method.

Comment: Error: "SomeLib.MainForm" does not contain a definition for "SaveSomething".

Comment: @JimKiely I've just tested the exact same code as what was above with the modification to `protected` and it works fine?

Comment: "MainForm.SaveSomething();" - This is how I called the method from within the doubleclick event method.  Any idea's?

Comment: Yes, don't do that. Use `SaveSomething();`, exactly like you have it. What you tried to do would be to expect a static method named `SaveSomething` on the class, not an instance of the class. `SaveSomething` is available in `this`, so you don't need to quantify it at all.