# WinForms raise event from another Form

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates

I have a main form named: MainForm and a child form named: ChildForm
I want to fill ChildForm's textboxes and in MainForm_ButtonClick i want to fire ChildForm_ButtonClick event.

## ChildForm:

```
public partial class ChildForm :Form
  {
        public delegate void delPassData(TextEdit text);

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string depart = "";

       MainForm mfrm = new MainForm();
       delPassData del = new delPassData(frm.funData);
       del(this.Item_CodeTextEdit);
    }
}
```

## MainForm:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
 {

 public void funData(TextEdit txtForm1)
    { 
        string ss = "";
        ss = txtForm1.Text;
        MessageBox.Show(ss);
    }

  private void NavigationPanelBtns_ButtonClick(object sender, ButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Button.Properties.Caption)
        {
            case "Save":
             // i want to call funData() here but i get an empty messageBox
            break;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: [Does this help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Looks like very beginner question (like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5743611/1997232) one). Use search harder!

Comment: @kyr Why dont you post that part in your question itself ? So it will be easy to understand and answer

Comment: You should use an MVC (Model View Controller) or MVP (Model View Presenter) approach for this. Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605161/how-to-make-form1-label-text-change-when-checkbox-on-form2-is-checked/15605436#15605436

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Child form

```
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    public ChildForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainForm.OnChildTextChanged += MainForm_OnChildTextChanged;
        MainForm.OnButtonClick += MainForm_OnButtonClick;
        bttn1.Visible = false;
    }

    void MainForm_OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.bttn1.PerformClick();
    }

    void MainForm_OnChildTextChanged(string value)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = value;
    }

    private void bttn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I am hide. But shows message");
    }

}

public class Bttn : Button
{
    public new void PerformClick()
    {
        this.OnClick(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Create a Parent Form

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public delegate void OnMyTextChanged(string value);
    public delegate void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public static event OnMyTextChanged OnChildTextChanged;
    public static event ButtonClicked OnButtonClick;

    ChildForm frm = new ChildForm();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm.Show();
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnChildTextChanged("this is new value");
        OnButtonClick(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your repsonse. Do you know where can i read some examples of Delegates?

Comment: I have update the answer with events. Please mark the answer if useful :)

Comment: this is exactly what i need. I'm sorry i couldn't explain it better. Thank you very much.

Comment: i would also like to ask something more. if i set button1.Visible = false; then this.button1.PerformClick(); doesn't work. I don't want button1 to be visible at runtime.

Comment: This is a custom requirement. So need to create a custom button in order to resolve the issue. Please find the updated answer

Comment: this is very helpful! but i can also write my code in:                       void Root_OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  MessageBox.Show("I can get data from here!"); }                              thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for posting this example, it helped my understanding of how delegates and static event handlers worked.  It was useful for understanding how business logic layer (Parent class above) could trigger control events on the UI (Child class above) in general.

Answer (score -2):

To access a textbox in another form:

1. Set `Modifier` property of the the textbox to `public` in child form.
2. In main form, access the textbox by an object of the child form.

   Eg:

   ```
   obj.txtBox.Text="MyValue";
   ```

To access an event in another form:

1. Set the event handling function to `public`.
2. Invoke the function by passing `null` as parameters by the object of the form.

   Eg:

   ```
   obj.MyButton_Click(null, null);
   ```

Comment: Regarding `MyButton_Click(null, null);`, don't set event `public`, it's bad. Instead set `MyButton` to be public and invoke event like this `MyButton.PerformClick()`.

Comment: i' ve tried MyButton.PerformClick(); but it only works on Form_Load event.